# "Has been" vs "was"

Tags: past-tense

Would you please explain the difference between these two sentences?

> Spain ceded (or gave) Puerto Rico to the United States. Since then, Puerto Rico **has been** a U.S. territory.
>
> Spain ceded(or gave) Puerto Rico to the United States. Since then, Puerto Rico **was** a U.S. territory.

I am stuck between 'has been' and 'was' in the above sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"has been"** is [present perfect](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/be). This means that the thing started happening in the past, and continues to happen in the present.

**"was"** is past simple.  This means that the thing started happening in the past, and then stopped happening in the past.

So "was" is inappropriate because Puerto Rico still continues to be a U.S. territory–it never stopped.  If it did stop, "was" would be correct (although "since then" would no longer be correct).

I hope that helps!